i hope to know the relationship of the joint name in urdf & ros2 control label & controller config file?
github issue link : https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/1539
I think that if the joint name in the ros2_control tag corresponds to the controller config, it can ensure that the controller transmits correct data to the hardware layer using the correct command interface. The joint name in the ros2_control tag corresponds to the joint name in urdf, which can ensure that the joint status broadcaster controller can publish the correct joint status, corresponding to the joint name in TF, so that rviz displays normally。

Your assumption is correct I guess, but what is your actual question?
